# FATAL Signal 11 while accessing SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase method - NDK

Tags: c++, sqlite, android-ndk, android-sqlite

I am working on 32 to 64bit migration part.
Now Application is working in few devices like One Plus 5(8xx processor) or One plus 7 pro (8xx processor) but the application crashing in Redmi, Realme, Samsung M40 which are 6xx processor

I am getting below stack trace

```
#01 0x0000000000398b10 /system/lib64/libart.so (art::MemMap::MapInternal(void*, unsigned long, int, int, int, long, bool)+88)
#02 0x00000000003987ac /system/lib64/libart.so (art::MemMap::MapAnonymous(char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, bool)+484)
#03 0x0000000000263520 /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::IndirectReferenceTable(unsigned long, art::IndirectRefKind, art::IndirectReferenceTable::ResizableCapacity, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+140)
#04 0x0000000000319d50 /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNIEnvExt::JNIEnvExt(art::Thread*, art::JavaVMExt*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+52)
#05 0x0000000000319c74 /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNIEnvExt::Create(art::Thread*, art::JavaVMExt*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+52)
#06 0x000000000049b170 /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateNativeThread(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, unsigned long, bool)+440)
#07 0x00000000003e3cbc /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread_nativeCreate(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, long, unsigned char)+156)
#08 0x0000000071cd4a7c /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0xa1a000)

#00 0x0000000002ecc990 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-non moving space (deleted) (offset 0x7000)
#01 0x00000000000212e8 /system/lib64/libopenjdk.so (Java_java_io_UnixFileSystem_checkAccess0+128)
#02 0x0000000071d26e10 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0xa1a000)
```

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7697e760 in tid 31901 (firebase-iid-ex), pid 31879 (docs.android)

Comment: You don't use some custom SQLite, do you? how do you trace this crash back to `getReadableDatabase()`?

Comment: No, I am using Android default Sqlite. I got this crashed dump but I added logs as well and from logs, the application crashed while going to access DB by getReadableDatabase() of the SqliteDatabase method.

Comment: I found one difference that One plus devices having 8xx Processor while the mentioned devices in the description are 6xx processors. Is there any dependency on the processor?

Comment: No, there should be no dependency on processor, but the RAM size could make a difference.

Comment: ok, so android:largeheap=true will work? I tried this but getting the same issue

Comment: No, when I speak about RAM size I mean how much the device has to offer. If that's the case, you cannot cure it with `largeheap`.

Comment: @AlexCohn, I have tested app in many devices Xiaomi, Samsung (S10, S9, M40, A7) but it's not working but in Nokia 6.1 plus, One plus (5, 7 pro) working fine. Is it depend on Stock Android?

Comment: *`Is it depend on Stock Android`* – this is a very good question. At any rate, I would suggest to open a new ticket at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new. The Google engineers that monitor that site may have tools to help you.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for you support. I have already raised on issue tracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167976846

Comment: They aren't very helpful  Does your app include NDK-built libraries at all?

Comment: In project, libssl.so, libcrypto.so (both are FIPS compatible), libc++_shared (NDK built lib), libcurl.a, libcrashlytics.so are used. Sqlitechipher is used too.

Comment: Could the Sqlitechipher be responsible?

Comment: It couldn't. Is there any restriction on the native library or access to its address in the latest version?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You complain that the problem happens on the same platform version, by switching from 32-bit to 64-bit libraries. There are definitely no additional restrictions that depend on bit-ness.